# Eclipse's convert to Maven does not allow using APK packaging

Tags: android, eclipse, maven

How can I enable on Eclipse Juno the APK packaging option?

When I select Configure > Convert to Maven, the packaging combobox shows only POM, JAR e WAR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not yet supported by the m2e-android plug-in. Please add an enhancement request here if you'd like to see this:

https://github.com/rgladwell/m2e-android/issues

Comment: How the app is deployed if the APK packaging is not available? Does Android supports apps in JAR package?

Comment: APK packaging is supported, just not for the "Convert to Maven" m2e feature.

Comment: @RicardoGladwell : As of Dec'13, this is still not supported. Can you please post some guidelines in the meantime, on how to proceed ? Is this to say that we cannot mavenize an existing Android project using m2e-android ? Or do I need to select any option (say apk) and later manually re-write the pom.xml with apk packaging ? Thanks !